# Taking natural log of $f(x) = 5^{x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x) = 5^{x^2}$$
I'm trying to figure out how to take the natural log of this problem. All rules that I can find for natural log don't explain what to do with multiple exponents. Can someone please explain how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: $5^{x^2}=e^{x^2\ln 5}$, so $\ln(5^{x^2})=x^2\ln 5$

Comment: you know that $log(5^{x^2}) = x^2log 5$ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the rule $\log(a^b) = b\log(a)$ as follows:

$$\log\left(5^{x^2}\right) = x^2\log(5).$$

Here $b=x^2$, and $a=5$.